# View Powerpoint web app presentation offline

Tags: powerpoint, onedrive

Is it possible to save and view presentations made web-compatible with the [Powerpoint Web App](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-on-a-webpage-FX102602487.aspx) offline? Simply saving the Powerpoint Web App page doesn't work.

Comment: do you have a portfolio or other way to connect to you?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Yes. Why? Is it related to this question?

Comment: no i was just curios